# Operations on a List of Vectors (Norm)

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a List containing vectors. The coordinates are random numbers:

```
r = {RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n], RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n], RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n]};
```

Now I want to calculate the Norm of each Vector (into another List). Is this possible without a loop? Something like

```
Norm[r,2]
```

Where 2 is the dimension (columns) in which the norm should be calculated.

Comment: Your question is unclear: what is n? Is each vector of length (dimension) n or of length (dimension) 3?

Comment: `Norm /@ Transpose[r]` would do it, no?

Comment: n is the amount of vectors - sorry (in my example 1000)

Comment: And thanks J.M. your answer works like a charm (I searched something similar to "arrayfun" in Matlab). If you want you can post it as answer and I'll ccheck it as accepted answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to Map[ ] the Norm function onto the list of vectors:

```
 Map[Norm, r]
```

If you think of r as being a matrix (with 3 rows and n columns, per the OPs code), this gives you a list, where each entry is the norm of the corresponding row in r. You can also use the infix notation for Map[ ] which is /@

```
Norm /@ r
```

If you want the Norm applied to the columns, then a Transpose[ ] is needed

```
 Norm/@ Transpose[r]
```

Comment: OP's vectors are columns of the array and not the rows, so a preliminary `Transpose[]` is needed...

Comment: I had interpreted n as the length of each of the vectors (i.e., as the rows of the matrix r) with the goal of finding the norm of the three rows. If n is the number of vectors, and you want the norm of each column, then indeed you need to do Norm/@ Transpose[r]